# Get input fields to change based on value typed (JS)

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get the fields to change based on value typed

If B1 weight = 100 - display (weight*1.5) in fields B32 and C32
If B2 gender = M   - display specific values in fields B5 and C5

there are hundreds but this is what I have so far. It makes logical sense to me so don't know what i did wrong / am missing.

I don't want a submit so needs to happen "real-time". Is that possible using the code below.

```js
<script>
function calcule2() {
 var i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  calcule();
 }
}
function calcule() {
 myForm.B5.value = IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "M", "0:45", IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "F", "0:45"));
 myForm.C5.value = IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "M", "0:32", IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "F", "0:36"));
 myForm.B32.value = (Math.round((IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "M", parseFloat(myForm.B1.value) * 0.75, IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "F", parseFloat(myForm.B1.value) * 0.75))) * 1)) / 1;
 myForm.C32.value = (Math.round((IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "M", parseFloat(myForm.B1.value) * 1.25, IF(parseFloat(myForm.B2.value) = "F", parseFloat(myForm.B1.value) * 1.25))) * 1)) / 1;
}
</script>
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" onChange="calcule2()" name="B1" value="100" class="info">WEIGHT<br/>
  <input type="text" onChange="calcule2()" name="B2" value="F" class="info">GENDER</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" onChange="calcule2()" name="B5" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="text" onChange="calcule2()" name="C5" value=""></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" onChange="calcule2()" name="B32" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="text" onChange="calcule2()" name="C32" value=""></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` is the way to go. However: '`if`' in js is lowercase and the comarison operator is '`==`'. '`=`' is the assignment operator.

Try something like:

```
switch(myForm.B2.value) {
 case 'F':
  myForm.B32.value = // do your calculation for gender female.. etc.
  ...
 break;
 case 'M'
 ...
}
```

Also for the gender selection consider using a `select` instead of (free) text input.

The one-line form you mention may be as this:

```
myForm.C5.value = myForm.B2.value == "M" ? "0:32" : "0:36";
```

It assigns C5 the value of "0:32" if the value of B2 is "M" and "0:36" otherwise.

Comment: I originally did this in excel and converted to HTML. Then modified each to have the correct form and field name.

So basically I will have to have them over 2 lines, instead of 1 line (well separated by case m / f.  Thanks. will try it out.